# Shift code rewards not showing up in my PS5 for Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I redeemed a whole bunch of [working shift codes](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key#Bookmark_Here) by registering on the [gearboxsoftware](https://shift.gearboxsoftware.com/rewards) website. I should have more than 100 golden keys by now for golden chest in the Borderlands 2. Some redemptions are shown below.

[image]

However, when I play Borderlands on my PS5 it does not show any golden keys on my account. I used the same email on both my PS5 and for login on Shift rewards website. Kindly help someone!

Comment: Do you have a character that has progressed far enough in the story for the Golden Key chest to be available?

Comment: I am at level 55, finished TVHM ready to move to UVHM after finishing some side quests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can read that you have used the same email for your SHIFT account and your PSN account, but have you actually linked both accounts together on the SHIFT website?

You can only redeem the codes in-game if both accounts are linked.
I did find an entry on the official 2K support that explains how to link the PSN account to the SHIFT account for Tiny Tina's Wonderland and I assume that it works the same way for Borderlands 2.

Official 2K Support Website Link: [[TINY TINA'S WONDERLANDS] SHIFT ACCOUNTS AND YOU](https://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/4418261268371--TINY-TINA-S-WONDERLANDS-SHIFT-ACCOUNTS-AND-YOU)

In the past Borderlands 2 had issues with SHIFT codes on PS3 consoles when you linked the accounts via the website. If that still happens for you on the PS5 the solution was in the past to delete the existing link and to re-link the accounts, but this time you start the process from the PS5 and not the website.

Comment: yes, they are linked. i restarted the game and all my golden keys and rewards slipped in for me. so happy :)

Comment: it's way too tedious to enter those codes on ps5, i'd rather copy paste using my PC :D